# C++: MSVC error C2668: ambiguous templated overload, works on GCC and CLang

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am getting MSVC C2668 error on this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    class B {
    public:
        bool isValid() const {return true;}
        void foo() const {};
    };
    std::vector<B> container;
};

template <class T>
inline void myForEach(const T &m, std::function<void (const typename T::B &)> action) {
    for(auto b : m.container)
        if(b.isValid())
            action(b);
}

template <class T>
inline void myForEach(T &m, std::function<void (typename T::B &)> action) {
    for(auto b : m.container)
        if(b.isValid())
            action(b);
}

void bar(const A& obj) {
    myForEach(obj, [&](const A::B& b){
        b.foo();
    });
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    A obj;
    bar(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that MSVC is not able to disambiguate the constness of the A object:

```
note: may be 'void myForEach<const A>(T &,std::function<void (A::B &)>)'
        with
        [
            T=const A
        ]
note: or 'void myForEach<A>(const T &,std::function<void (const A::B &)>)'
        with
        [
            T=A
        ]
```

Is there something that cannot be disambiguated in this code? How can I do to have this working with proper const-correctness?
GCC and CLang build without errors.
I am using VS 2019, v16.7.3 with MSVC 16.6.30225.117.

Comment: Don't know the reason for the first question. However, lambda is not a `std::function` therefore deduction needs help always. Such as: 1. `static_cast<std::function<void (const &...)>>(lambda)`, 2. provide templae parameter: `template <class T, typename Callable>
void MyForEach(const T& m, Callable action)`

Comment: Thanks @JeJo, I didn't know that lambdas and std::function are not interchangeable (I found part of this code in a library and I assumed that was written correctly)! It makes a lot of sense and solution n.2 you proposed works well!! Thank you!